# How to open a file through intent in latest android versions?

Tags: android, android-intent, storage-access-framework

In Android versions  before SAF, to make the App able to open a supported file from a file manager or whatever other app was enough to

1. create an intent filter to make the app registered for that file type
2. load the file through the uri obtained with `getIntent().getData();`

Now this doesn't work, because although the intent filter continues to make the app appear as choose when you click on it from whatever file manager, the App seems is not able to load the file using the uri obtained with `getIntent().getData();`

To load the file I have tried

```
Uri uri=getIntent().getData();
DocumentFile openedFile=DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri);
```

but `openedFile` results always `null`

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: @Andy I have read it and I haven't found the answer to my question. There is written how to pick file but it is not explained how to pick file from the invoker intent uri when file is opened from other app with intent filter. If I have missed something could you give me a working example answering the question?

Comment: For what do you need a DocumentFile instance? To load a file open an InputStream and read from the stream.

Comment: Tell the value of uri.toString().

Comment: it changes, e.g. if I open it from default files app  and the file is in download folder `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A100000006` 
 if I use another app something like `content://com.someappusedtoopen.file/506!/somefile.someextension`

Comment: Ok. But nothing has changed. It is you using a DocumentFile instance on uries of new providers. I ask you again for what you use a DocumentFile. Not needed to read the file.

Comment: @blackapps I need to read the opened file DocumentFile, it should be edited and deleted from app once opened

Comment: Yes. And i told you already twice that you do not need a DocumentFile instance. What you need instead i also already told you.

Comment: @blackapps I need it since the api supposed to work on file receives a DocumentFile, otherwise I have to write a lot of additional code. DocumentFile repesents a file and has a method fromSingleUri that should work with file Uri, it absurd that doesn't work, It' not me that is dong a weird thing expecting an API to be coherent with itself .

Comment: We still do not precisely  know why you want that DocumentFile. You can do without if you want tor read/write the uri. Now please tell. Third time i ask. I think you can instead drop a lot of code when you just use the uri.